# Linux randomly routes packets to the wrong interface

Tags: linux, vpn, routing, nat

I own a dedicated server with some kvm vps running for my clients.
My main network is 192.168.1.0/24.
The vps have a dedicated network 192.168.2.0/24 on a bridge interface brv6.
The ipv6 traffic goes through my isp router as each vps have it's own ipv6 address.
But for my security, the ipv4 traffic is routed through a nordvpn wireguard vpn (10.5.0.1/24).
Here is the routing table for the vps:

```
default dev wg0 scope link
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 scope link
```

Everything from brv6 use this routing table.

```
ip rule add iif brv6 table vps
```

Here is an illustration:

192.168.2.0/24 <==> 10.5.0.1/24 <==> Internet

VPS <==> NordVPN <==> Internet

As nordvpn servers don't know the network 192.168.2.0/24, i put a NAT between 192.168.2.0/24 and 10.5.0.1/24 so that every packet is NATed with my nordvpn client ip (10.5.0.2).

```
iptables -t nat -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE
```

But sometimes (randomly), some clients tell me they don't have ipv4 access.
After checking, i found some packets are not going through wireguard, but are in the physical interface (brv6 physical nic).

```
tcpdump -nni enp3s0f1 ip
```

Also, `conntrack -L` shows connections with source address unNATed (in 192.168.2.0/24 instead of 10.5.0.2)

I really can't find a way to get this working.
Maybe you guys have an idea ?

The server is running debian 11 on Linux 5.10

Comment: The routing tables are the same on all vps:
A default route to 192.168.2.1

Comment: ethtool is installed but does't seems to change my config. Anyway, there is my /etc/network/interfaces : [https://pastebin.com/iC3hJgYa](https://pastebin.com/iC3hJgYa)

Comment: What program sets the mac address on the bridge and creates interfaces for the virtual machines to use? (on this site we like to get rid of comments that are *no longer needed* - whenever you think a comment asking for clarifications was useful in getting towards a clear question, don't add more comments - just use the [edit] button on the question)

Comment: i use virt-install to create virtual machines, it automatically choose a random mac address

Comment: Libvirt does a few things automatically, as might whatever is managing your wireguard setup, and whatever is setting up your physical NIC. On the host, try dumping the list of interfaces+addresses / routes / firewall rules (`ip a l` / `ip -4 r` / `iptables -vnL`), if you do not see any differences between intended and degraded status, at least it might serve to better understand the situation where you are encountering the problem.

Comment: Wireguard is configured to not touch the routing table (with `Table = off` in the config file). After deleting iptables rules responsible for blocking broadcast/multicast, the issue seems to be resolved. I'll keep you informed in case this continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hard searching, i found the problem.
Virtual machines inside the brv6 network were sending ARP broadcasts to get the brv6 gateway MAC address.
brv6 and br0 are both on a switch.
But the br0 interface was responding to the ARP packets even if it's not for it.
So the VM got an ARP entry for brv6 with the MAC of br0 (which they can't reach).

To fix the problem, i set up arptables rules to block ARP in destination to 192.168.2.1 (brv6) from reaching br0.
And vice-versa: block ARP to br0 from being received by brv6.

```
arptables -A INPUT -i br0 -d 192.168.2.1 -j DROP
arptables -A INPUT -i brv6 -d 192.168.1.138 -j DROP
```

I don't know if this is a feature or a bug in the linux kernel.
Anyway, i found the solution and hope this could help anyone.

Comment: This results from Linux using the Weak [Host Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model), including ARP behavior. You don't have to use arptables. Per-interface ARP settings can be used: [`arp_filter`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v5.15#n1529) or [`arp_ignore`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v5.15#n1580)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i added `net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore=1`, deleted my arptables rules and the problem seems to be fixed. No bad replies from wrong interfaces.